# Zero code coverage with jacoco with tomcat

Tags: jacoco

I'm trying to get the code coverage information for an application running in tomcat. I started with tomcat adding the following java arguments as below:

```
-javaagent:C:/Users/angel/Desktop/CodeCoverage/jacoco-0.7.5.201505241946/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=C:\Users\angel\Desktop\Code\new\jacoco.exec,append=true,includes=myapp.*
```

I could see the `jacoco.exec` generated, but it's not getting updated even after I stop Tomcat.
I also tried the below option, getting code coverage information using `tcp`:

```
-javaagent:C:/Users/angel/Desktop/CodeCoverage/jacoco-0.7.5.201505241946/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=C:\Users\angel\Desktop\Code\jacoco.exec,append=true,jmx=true,includes=myapp.*
```

But still no update on the coverage information even after stopping tomcat. Please suggest me to get this done.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I myself figured out the issue.

I just removed the myapp.* in the includes and just put a * and it solved my problem. I have given as below:

-javaagent:C:/Users/angel/Desktop/CodeCoverage/jacoco-0.7.5.201505241946/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=C:\Users\angel\Desktop\Code\new\jacoco.exec,append=true,output=tcpserver,address=localhost,port=36320,**includes=***

Thanks
Angel